# Android studio RecyclerView with firebase problem?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-layout, android-recyclerview

If i complete those edit text with what i want,it will show the info to my fire data base but in the recycler view never show the third `holder(holder.textViewZ.setText(model.getWhy)`. Do you have any idea why is this happening?

This is my main activity

---

```
package com.example.incercarefirebase;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.graphics.ColorSpace;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.SuccessContinuation;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.net.IDN;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnSaveRecycler;
    private EditText etNAME, etSurrname, etZ;

    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options;
    private DatabaseReference rootDatabaseref;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, MyViewHolder> adapter;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etNAME = findViewById(R.id.etNAME);
        etSurrname = findViewById(R.id.etSurrname);
        etZ = findViewById(R.id.etZ);

        btnSaveRecycler = findViewById(R.id.btnSaveRecycler);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewID);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        rootDatabaseref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


        btnSaveRecycler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int id = Integer.parseInt(etNAME.getText().toString());
                String name = etSurrname.getText().toString();
                String why = etZ.getText().toString();
                String key = rootDatabaseref.push().getKey();

                rootDatabaseref.child(key).child("ID").setValue(id);
                rootDatabaseref.child(key).child("Name").setValue(name);
                rootDatabaseref.child(key).child("Why").setValue(why);
            }
        });

        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>().setQuery(rootDatabaseref, Model.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, MyViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Model model) {

                holder.textviewName.setText(model.getName());
                holder.textviewID.setText(model.getID());
                holder.textViewZ.setText(model.getWhy());


            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_view_layout, parent, false);

                return new MyViewHolder(v);
            }
        };

        adapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

This is my viewHolder

```
package com.example.incercarefirebase;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textviewID, textviewName, textViewZ;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textviewID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
        textviewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewZ = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewZ);


    }
}
```

This is my model

```
package com.example.incercarefirebase;

public class Model {
    private int ID;
    private String Name;
    private String Why;

    public Model() {
    }

    public Model(int ID, String name, String why) {
        this.ID = ID;
        Name = name;
        Why = why;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getWhy() {
        return Why;
    }

    public void setWhy(String why) {
        Why = why;
    }
}
```

This is the single_view_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name..."
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewZ"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="aaaaa"
        android:textSize="30dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

This is the main XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNAME"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="ID"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSurrname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etZ"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey :) You should give debugging a try. You could save yourself hours of waiting for someone to read all that code and post the answer :)

Comment: I need all code or send your code to my email.

Comment: which is your email?